# Error with the function random.choice

Tags: python-3.x, random, python-imaging-library

Using this code:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageChops import subtract
import numpy
import math
import time
import glob
import sys
import os
import logging
import random


def GreenScreen(infile, inbg ,outfile='output.png', keyColor=None, tolerance=None):
    """
    http://gc-films.com/chromakey.html
    http://www.cs.utah.edu/~michael/chroma/
    :param infile:      Greenscreen image location
    :param inbg:        Background image location
    :param outfile:     Output file location
    :param keyColor:    greenscreen color; it can be any singular color
    :param tolerance:   tolerance of cleaning
    :return:
    """

    if not keyColor:
        keyColor = [151,44,21] #Y,Cb, and Cr values of the greenscreen

    if not tolerance:
        tolerance = [100,130] #Allowed Distance from Values

    #open files
    inDataFG = Image.open('/home/leonardo/Scrivania/KVfnt.jpg').convert('YCbCr')
    BG = random.choice(os.listdir('/home/leonardo/Scrivania/background')).convert('RGB')
    [Y_key, Cb_key, Cr_key] = keyColor
    [tola, tolb]= tolerance

    (x,y) = inDataFG.size #get dimensions
    foreground = numpy.array(inDataFG.getdata()) #make array from image
    maskgen = numpy.vectorize(colorclose) #vectorize masking function


    alphaMask = maskgen(foreground[:,1],foreground[:,2] ,Cb_key, Cr_key, tola, tolb) #generate mask
    alphaMask.shape = (y,x) #make mask dimensions of original image
    imMask = Image.fromarray(numpy.uint8(alphaMask))#convert array to image
    invertMask = Image.fromarray(numpy.uint8(255-255*(alphaMask/255))) #create inverted mask with extremes

    #create images for color mask
    colorMask = Image.new('RGB',(x,y),tuple([0,0,0]))
    allgreen = Image.new('YCbCr',(x,y),tuple(keyColor))

    colorMask.paste(allgreen,invertMask) #make color mask green in green values on image
    inDataFG = inDataFG.convert('RGB') #convert input image to RGB for ease of working with
    cleaned = subtract(inDataFG,colorMask) #subtract greens from input
    BG.paste(cleaned,imMask)#paste masked foreground over background

    # BG.show() #display cleaned image
    BG.save(outfile, "JPEG") #save cleaned image

def colorclose(Cb_p,Cr_p, Cb_key, Cr_key, tola, tolb):
    temp = math.sqrt((Cb_key-Cb_p)**2+(Cr_key-Cr_p)**2)
    if temp < tola:
        z = 0.0
    elif temp < tolb:
        z = ((temp-tola)/(tolb-tola))
    else:
        z = 1.0
    return 255.0*z

def check_folders(logger):
    if not os.path.exists('out/'):
        os.mkdir('out/')
    if not os.path.exists('background/'):
        os.mkdir('background/')
        logger.error("Place background images in background/")
        sys.exit()
    if not os.path.exists('in/'):
        os.mkdir('in/')
        logger.error("Place input files in in/")
        sys.exit()

def begin_greenbox(logger):
    """
    For all backgrounds loop through all input files into the out file
    """
    for bg in glob.glob('background/*'):
        if not('.jpg' or '.png' in bg.lower()):
            continue
        bg_name = bg.split('/')[-1].lower().strip('.jpg').strip('.png').strip('.jpeg')
        for picture in glob.glob('in/*'):
            if not('.jpg' or '.png' in picture.lower()):
                continue
            pic_name = picture.split('/')[-1].lower().strip('.JPG').strip('.png').strip('.jpeg')
            output_file = 'out/' + bg_name + ' ' + pic_name + '.jpg'

            one_pic = time.time()
            GreenScreen(infile=picture ,inbg=bg, outfile=output_file)
            one_pic_time_done = time.time()

            time_arr.append(one_pic_time_done-one_pic)
            logger.info(time_arr)
            logger.info('done : %s' % pic_name)

def start_logging():
    logging.basicConfig()
    logger = logging.getLogger('greenbox')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    return logger

if __name__ == '__main__':
    time_start = time.time()
    time_arr = []
    logger = start_logging()
    logger.info("Start time: %s" % time_start)
    check_folders(logger)    
    begin_greenbox(logger)
    time_end = time.time()
    logger.info("End time: %s" % time_end)
```

I obtain this error:

```
INFO:greenbox:Start time: 1452730719.31
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chromakeyy.py", line 115, in <module>
    begin_greenbox(logger)
  File "chromakeyy.py", line 96, in begin_greenbox
    GreenScreen(infile=picture ,inbg=bg, outfile=output_file)
  File "chromakeyy.py", line 33, in GreenScreen
    BG = Image.open(random.choice(os.listdir('/home/leonardo/Scrivania/background'))).convert('RGB')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2288, in open
    fp = builtins.open(fp, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bai19-266x400.jpg'
```

Before using the command random.choice in line 33, everything was ok. What is the problem? Why is it giving me this error? Is there another method to open a random image from a specific folder? Thank you.

Comment: Instead of linking to an external website for your code, please place it inline in your question. This is for two reasons: first, it is easier to answer if all the relevant information is right there, and second it makes sure this question stays relevant even if the external website ceases to exist.

Comment: I linked it to an external website because i had problem using the command to insert code

Comment: To format as code, indent all lines an extra four spaces and be sure there is an empty line above and below the code snippet. There should be a button on the editor to do this for you: it looks like two curly braces. Just select all your code and click that button.

Comment: Maybe the problem was the four spaces. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states that the file you are trying to open does not exist. This is most likely because os.listdir(path) returns only the file names in 'path', and not the full directory and filename.

In your case, it did select a random file named 'bai19-266x400.jpg', which you then tried to open. When you should be opening '/home/leonardo/Scrivania/background/bai19-266x400.jpg'. Something more like this should work:

```
Path = '/home/leonardo/Scrivania/background'
FullPath = os.path.join(Path, random.choice(os.listdir(Path)))
BG = Image.open(FullPath).convert('RGB')
```

Comment: Make that: `FullPath = os.path.join(Path, random.choice(os.listdir(Path)))`; you're forgetting to include the path separator, so it's going to try to open files named `backgroundXXXX`, not files _in_ `background` named `XXXX`. Using `os.path.join` is always good form (both for avoiding doubled slashes if an existing path already contains them, and to avoid hardcoding the OS path separator, though obviously it's already hardcoded in the path itself here).

Comment: Well it took me 3 edits, but @ShadowRanger that is a good point.

Comment: Thank you for your answers but with the bartushk's code the script gives me not only an output image but 5 (because there are 5 files in background) while with ShadowRanger's code appears this error:   File "chromakeyy.py", line 11, in <module>
    import path
ImportError: No module named path. I have written ShadowRanger's code in this way: FullPath = os.path.join(Path, random.choice(os.listdir('/home/leonardo/Scrivania/background/')))

Comment: I'm not sure about returning 5 files, but I can say that to use os.path, you do not need to import path. You only need to import os, which you already have done.

Comment: Have I written ShadowRanger's code in the right way? How can I use bartushk's code to have only one output and not 5?

Comment: @Leonardo: You don't import `path`, it's `os.path` (though as a coincidence of implementation in this case, `import os` gets you `os.path` as well; that's not normally guaranteed, but it is in this case).

Comment: @Leonardo: You passed a str literal to `os.listdir`; you should be passing the same string as the first argument to `os.path.join`; if `Path` is a different string, then you'll get the wrong output (though not five outputs...).

Comment: @ShadowRanger sorry but I have not understood. What should I import?

Comment: @Leonardo: Nothing. You already did `import os`; if you want, you can add `import os.path`, but it's not necessary in this particular case.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Now I have understood. Now I have this error  with your code http://pastebin.com/UQPk2BeH. Maybe I have mistaken in changing the strings (I have started programming some days ago).

Comment: @Leonardo: That has nothing to do with the problems addressed to date. I suggest you try to figure out where `BG` was supposed to be defined, and make sure it gets defined before it is used.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I have changed the code I had in line 33 with yours in this way: http://pastebin.com/xTTU51sN. What have I mistaken?

Comment: Nothing. It's a little long (I'd store the path in a variable and pass the variable twice, instead of the long literal), and it's bad form to end path literals with a `/` (`os.path.join` handles that for you though by deduping the separator). But it's fine. You have a completely different problem, unrelated to choosing files.

Comment: So? What code should I write to open come random image from the folder? I'm going crazy :(

Answer (score 0):

Trying and trying, I have finally resolved the problem of the multiple output images. The cause was the presence of the cicle  `for` and removing it everyhting now is okay. Thank you all.